# getsockname() c not setting value

Tags: c, networking, null

I'm trying to get the local IP used for a connection established. However, for some reason, I'm unable to use getsockname because it never sets any data in my sockaddr.

```
int fd = socket(/* params */);
int len;
struct sockaddr_in _self;
/* Connection code, I know the connection succeeds and I've tested */
memset(&_self, 0, sizeof (struct sockaddr_in));
getsockname(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &_self, &len);
printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(_self.sin_addr);
```

However, when the program gets to printf, it always terminates due to a 'Segmentation fault', which I think is when it tries to access memory that it hasn't set (am I correct in this assumption?) If so, does that mean that getsockname is failing?

Comment: you can check getsockanme result (0:sucess, -1 error and errno is set).

Comment: @mpromonet I just checked, it returns 0 and errno is also 0

Comment: In the man page for getsockname, it says: The addrlen argument should be initialized to indicate the amount of space (in bytes) pointed to by addr.  It doesn't look like len is initialized in your code. Not sure if that's related to your problem, though.

Comment: Your code seeems to works see test : http://ideone.com/nDusgq it print 0.0.0.0. Perhaps are you using different socket initailization ?

Comment: @Quercus has it - failure to initialize `len` is the main problem in the code shown so far. If you show a complete program, maybe more problems will be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialise `len` to be the maximum allowed size *before* calling `getsockname()` (ie, the size of the structure). This length value is them modified by the call to contain the *actual* length.

You should also ensure that the socket descriptor has been bound. Your test seems to indicate it's for an established session but the code is unclear in that it only contains a `socket()` call.

As a baseline, use the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main (void) {
    int fd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in _self;
    int len = sizeof (_self);

    memset (&_self, 0, len);
    bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &_self, len);

    memset (&_self, 42, len);
    getsockname (fd, (struct sockaddr *) &_self, &len);
    printf ("%s\n", inet_ntoa (_self.sin_addr));

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs `0.0.0.0` as expected.

Comment: I changed it to say int len = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);, and it still didn't work, so I'm assuming I did something wrong. What do you mean by maximum allowed size?

Comment: @user1772510, that's precisely what I meant. However, I'd suggest posting a more complete example since the one you've given has syntax errors. Best would be to provide a complete minimal example that exhibits the problem. There's no point in hamstringing us :-)